# Is there a word that means "like a cathedral"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to describe a certain orderliness found in music like Bach and elsewhere, that I find to resemble (in metaphorical terms) the architecture and construction of a cathedral. It would be for use in a sentence such as the following:

"The music he wrote had a **cathedral-like** orderliness."

Instead of "cathedral-like," however, I would like to use a word such as "cathedraline" or "cathedralesque." But I'm not sure a word like those actually exists. Any help welcome, many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Cathedralesque* is indeed a word and it is listed in *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/28939?redirectedFrom=cathedralesque#eid9851033)*.

> *adj.* like a cathedral.

I've even found an example similar to yours:

> One of the many astonishing things about *Die Meistersinger* is how the little Greek and Roman plot blossoms, in Wagner's shaping imagination, into a dramatic and musical structure of **cathedralesque** proportions.
>
> <sub>*[First Intermissions: Twenty-one Great Operas Explored, Explained and Brought to Life from the Met](https://books.google.es/books?id=jfz-DkPeyv0C&pg=PA107&dq=%22Greek%20and%20Roman%20plot%20blossoms%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRgv396rz4AhXdlP0HHV_4BHcQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=cathedralesque&f=false)* - M. Owen Lee</sub>

*OED* lists *cathedralic* and *cathedralish* also for the same meaning but they are *[less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cathedralesque%2C%20cathedralic%2C%20cathedralish&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccathedralesque%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccathedralic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccathedralish%3B%2Cc0)* (based on Google Ngram) and less suitable. *Cathedral-like* is the most common adjective among all and it is listed in *OED* also, however you didn't want to use it per your question; and it is possibly less suitable than *cathedralesque* for your example.

Answer (score 0):

[Cathedral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathedral) actually means the housing of the seat of a bishop, although the term is often used for an  imposing building. So, a term referring to a *cathedral* may not be what you want
I would suggest [edificial](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/edificial) as useful for your purpose.

> The music he wrote had an *edificial* orderliness.

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/edificial) comes close to providing a definition of *edificial* that meets your need.

Comment: The seat of a bishop is a _cathedra_, not a cathedral. _Cathedral_ is in fact just an adjective derived from that word, meaning ‘pertaining to a cathedra’; the main noun ‘church’ has been washed away by the centuries. Since the adjective _cathedral_ means, essentially, ‘chair-like’, I agree that it’s probably not the best term for the context sought here; but the inaccuracy of the rest stays my upvoting finger.